# Difference between two string as substring in python

Tags: python, string

I have two filepath as strings

```
string1 = r"C:\Users\Admin"  
string2= "C:\Users\Admin\Context1\Context2\filepath.dat"
```

How can I get the difference as "`Context1\Context2\filepath.dat`"

As of now I am iterating string1 by characters and comparing with string2 when it fails I am returning `string2[index:]`

there should be something easier pythonic way to do this. Or point me to the documentation.  Please see me as novice in python. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that these strings happen to be file paths, or are you asking specifically how to get a relative file path from two absolute file paths?

Comment: what if the 1st string is `string1 = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\filepath.dat'`

Comment: @rawing, All my inputs are going to be filepaths. But I am getting as string in the function where I do changes. Also In my case string1 is always going to be ancestral root of string2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also In my case string1 is always going to be ancestral root of
>   string2

```
string2[len(string1)+1:]
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as replacing the string1 with empty string in string2

```
string2.replace(string1,"")
```